# NameNotFoundException in WebSphere 8

Tags: spring, hibernate, websphere

Good Morning.
I need ti fix a "UnsuportedOperationException" between JPA, Hibernate and WebSPhere 8 when i mark a Transaction for Rollback.

I have this class:

```
package es.nspt.hiber.team.utils;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException;
import javax.transaction.HeuristicRollbackException;
import javax.transaction.InvalidTransactionException;
import javax.transaction.NotSupportedException;
import javax.transaction.RollbackException;
import javax.transaction.Status;
import javax.transaction.Synchronization;
import javax.transaction.SystemException;
import javax.transaction.Transaction;
import javax.transaction.TransactionManager;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;
import javax.transaction.xa.XAResource;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform;

public class WebSphereUOWTransactionLookup extends AbstractJtaPlatform {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6514686920271789210L;
        private static final String UOW_MANAGER_JNDI = "java:comp/websphere/UOWManager";
        private static final String UOW_SYNCHRONIZATION_MANAGER_JNDI = "java:comp/websphere/UOWSynchronizationRegistry";
        public static final String UT_NAME = "java:comp/UserTransaction";

        @Override
        protected TransactionManager locateTransactionManager() {
                return new TransactionManagerAdapter();
        }

        @Override
        protected UserTransaction locateUserTransaction() {
                return (UserTransaction) jndiService().locate(UT_NAME);
        }

        public class TransactionManagerAdapter implements TransactionManager {

                private final Class uowManagerClass;
                private final Class uowSynchronizationRegistryClass;
                private Object uowManager;
                private Object uowSynchronizationRegistry;
                private final Method registerSynchronizationMethod;
                private final Method setRollbackOnlyMethod;

                private final Method getLocalIdMethod;

                @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
                private TransactionManagerAdapter() {
                        try {
                                uowManagerClass = Class.forName("com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWManager");
                                setRollbackOnlyMethod = uowManagerClass.getMethod("setRollbackOnly", new Class[] {});

                                uowSynchronizationRegistryClass = Class.forName("com.ibm.websphere.uow.UOWSynchronizationRegistry");

                                registerSynchronizationMethod = uowSynchronizationRegistryClass.getMethod("registerInterposedSynchronization", new Class[] { Synchronization.class });
                                Class extendedJTATransactionClass = Class.forName("com.ibm.websphere.jtaextensions.ExtendedJTATransaction");
                                getLocalIdMethod = extendedJTATransactionClass.getMethod("getLocalId", null);

                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
                                throw new HibernateException(cnfe);
                        } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
                                throw new HibernateException(nsme);
                        }
                }

                /**
                 * Lazily loaded because UOW_MANAGER_JNDI isn't always available on
                 * Hibernate startup (when
                 * HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory is called).
                 */
                private Object getUowManager() {
                        if (uowManager == null) {
                                uowManager = jndiService().locate(UOW_MANAGER_JNDI);
                        }
                        return uowManager;
                }

                private Object getUowSynchronizationRegistry() {
                        if (uowSynchronizationRegistry == null) {
                                uowSynchronizationRegistry = jndiService().locate(UOW_SYNCHRONIZATION_MANAGER_JNDI);
                        }
                        return uowSynchronizationRegistry;
                }

                public void begin() throws NotSupportedException, SystemException {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }

                public void commit() throws RollbackException, HeuristicMixedException, HeuristicRollbackException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, SystemException {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }

                @Override
                public int getStatus() throws SystemException {
                        return getTransaction() == null ? Status.STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION : getTransaction().getStatus();
                }

                public Transaction getTransaction() throws SystemException {
                        return new TransactionAdapter();
                }

                public void resume(Transaction txn) throws InvalidTransactionException, IllegalStateException, SystemException {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }

                public void rollback() throws IllegalStateException, SecurityException, SystemException {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }

                public void setRollbackOnly() throws IllegalStateException, SystemException {
                        try {
                                setRollbackOnlyMethod.invoke(getUowManager(), new Object[] {});
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                throw new HibernateException(e);
                        }
                }

                public void setTransactionTimeout(int i) throws SystemException {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }

                public Transaction suspend() throws SystemException {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }

                public class TransactionAdapter implements Transaction {

                        private final Object extendedJTATransaction;

                        private TransactionAdapter() {
                                extendedJTATransaction = jndiService().locate("java:comp/websphere/ExtendedJTATransaction");
                        }

                        public void registerSynchronization(final Synchronization synchronization) throws RollbackException, IllegalStateException, SystemException {

                                try {
                                        registerSynchronizationMethod.invoke(getUowSynchronizationRegistry(), new Object[] { synchronization });
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                        throw new HibernateException(e);
                                }

                        }

                        public int hashCode() {
                                return getLocalId().hashCode();
                        }

                        public boolean equals(Object other) {
                                if (!(other instanceof TransactionAdapter))
                                        return false;
                                TransactionAdapter that = (TransactionAdapter) other;
                                return getLocalId().equals(that.getLocalId());
                        }

                        private Object getLocalId() {
                                try {
                                        return getLocalIdMethod.invoke(extendedJTATransaction, null);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                        throw new HibernateException(e);
                                }
                        }

                        public void commit() throws RollbackException, HeuristicMixedException, HeuristicRollbackException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, SystemException {
                                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                        }

                        public boolean delistResource(XAResource resource, int i) throws IllegalStateException, SystemException {
                                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                        }

                        public boolean enlistResource(XAResource resource) throws RollbackException, IllegalStateException, SystemException {
                                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                        }

                        public int getStatus() throws SystemException {
                                return new Integer(0).equals(getLocalId()) ? Status.STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION : Status.STATUS_ACTIVE;
                        }

                        public void rollback() throws IllegalStateException, SystemException {
                                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                        }

                        public void setRollbackOnly() throws IllegalStateException, SystemException {
                                try {
                                        setRollbackOnlyMethod.invoke(getUowManager(), new Object[] {});
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                        throw new HibernateException(e);
                                }
                        }
                }

        }

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        public Object getTransactionIdentifier(Transaction transaction) {
                // WebSphere, however, is not a sane JEE/JTA container…
                return new Integer(transaction.hashCode());
        }

}
```

But when my App Start a Transaction i see this error in the log:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/websphere/ExtendedJTATransaction]
        at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:68)
        at 
es.nspt.hiber.team.utils
.WebSphereUOWTransactionLookup$TransactionManagerAdapter$TransactionAdapter.<init>(WebSphereUOWTransactionLookup.java:133)
        at 
es.nspt.hiber.team
.utils.WebSphereUOWTransactionLookup$TransactionManagerAdapter$TransactionAdapter.<init>(WebSphereUOWTransactionLookup.java:128)
        at 
es.nspt.hiber.team.utils
.WebSphereUOWTransactionLookup$TransactionManagerAdapter.getTransaction(WebSphereUOWTransactionLookup.java:101)
        at 
es.nspt.hiber.team.utils
.WebSphereUOWTransactionLookup$TransactionManagerAdapter.getStatus(WebSphereUOWTransactionLookup.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.isActive(JtaStatusHelper.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.TransactionManagerBasedSynchronizationStrategy.canRegisterSynchronization(TransactionManagerBasedSynchronizationStrategy.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform.canRegisterSynchronization(AbstractJtaPlatform.java:148)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.attemptToRegisterJtaSync(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:247)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.pulse(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:284)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1212)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:188)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:541)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1788.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:285)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:252)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1791.merge(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.integration.jpa.core.DefaultJpaOperations.persistOrMerge(DefaultJpaOperations.java:271)
        at org.springframework.integration.jpa.core.DefaultJpaOperations.merge(DefaultJpaOperations.java:212)
        at org.springframework.integration.jpa.core.JpaExecutor.executeOutboundJpaOperation(JpaExecutor.java:244)
        at org.springframework.integration.jpa.outbound.JpaOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(JpaOutboundGateway.java:80)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:170)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
        ... 243 more
Caused by: javax.naming.ConfigurationException: A JNDI operation on a "java:" name cannot be completed because the server runtime is not able to associate the operation's thread with any J2EE application component.  This condition can occur when the JNDI client using the "java:" name is not executed on the thread of a server application request.  Make sure that a J2EE application does not execute JNDI operations on "java:" names within static code blocks or in threads created by that J2EE application.  Such code does not necessarily run on the thread of a server application request and therefore is not supported by JNDI operations on "java:" names. [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/websphere not found in context "java:".]
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.throwExceptionIfDefaultJavaNS(javaURLContextImpl.java:522)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.throwConfigurationExceptionWithDefaultJavaNS(javaURLContextImpl.java:552)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookupExt(javaURLContextImpl.java:481)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookupExt(javaURLContextRoot.java:485)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:396)
        at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:157)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:426)
        at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:65)
        ... 273 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/websphere not found in context "java:".
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1969)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.retrieveBinding(NameSpace.java:1376)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1219)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1141)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookupExt(UrlContextImpl.java:1436)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookupExt(javaURLContextImpl.java:477)
```

Answer (score 1):

Exception clearly indicate that system is `Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/websphere/ExtendedJTATransaction]`. Make sure the mentioned JNDI entry exist in your WebSphere Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The JNDi name sometimes is not visible because Websphere don't run the application in the same Java context that the WebSphere server. I can see the JNDi names when my application is starting, but no when the app is running and working.

Finally I implemented another solution to my problem , discarding this code. Thanks all for the responses.